# How to install cabal packages with extra libraries under Windows?

Tags: windows, haskell, linker, cabal

I'm trying to install [monadiccp](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monadiccp) with the "RuntimeGecode" flag so that it includes the Gecode libraries:

```
cabal install monadiccp --flags="RuntimeGecode Debug" --extra-lib-dirs="D:\Programme\Gecode\lib;d:\programme\Gecode\bin" --extra-include-dirs=D:\Programme\Gecode\include\
```

But that doesn't work, it fails with:

```
ld.exe: cannot find -lgecodesupport
ld.exe: cannot find -lgecodeset
```

And so on... See the [-v3 log output](http://hpaste.org/73854).

What am I doing wrong? The libraries don't seem any special, so are there some extra steps I need to do in Windows?

Update: The binaries downloadable from gecode.org are compiled with Visual Studio and aren't compatible with gcc (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8683381/60982) for the root problem). As suggested by Stephen, I'll try to build Gecode with MinGW/MSYS from source now.

Comment: Have you installed and are running from MinGW / MSYS? GHC bundles `gcc` and some of the build utils, but generally you need MinGW / MSYS to build bindings.

Comment: I just installed the Haskell Platform 2012.2 and this already has MinGW in it. Do I need MSYS separately? Shouldn't the log complain about that?

Comment: You need the separate distributions of MinGW and MSys from MinGW.org.

Comment: Ok I've installed it and added it to the path, but still get the same error. I updated the log paste.

Comment: Are run running the MSYS shell? The updated log looks similar to the previous one. Also how have you installed the original Gecode libraries? Ideally you might want to rebuild them in MSYS first.

Comment: No I didn't run it in MSYS shell. I updated the log paste when running in MSYS shell, still looks quite similar. Do I really need to build the libraries? Isn't the purpose of binaries not having to do that?

Comment: It looks like the binaries from Gecode.org are for Visual Studio. To ensure you have the development headers etc. I'd say you are best of building the generic source package under MinGW / MSYS.

Comment: Well... damn http://www.gecode.org/pipermail/users/2010-February/002829.html I'll try it anyway and will ask on their mailing list when I get to build errors.