# What am I missing trying to call gcc-compiled code from MSVC?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, binary-decision-diagram, cudd

My C/C++ perks are a bit rusty. Last time I have used them like 30 year ago :)

I have [CUDD](https://github.com/ivmai/cudd) library built from sources at Win10 using MINGW64 environment from MSYS2.

```
git clone https://github.com/ivmai/cudd.git
cd cudd
autoreconf -f -i
mkdir build
cd build
../configure "CFLAGS=-fPIC -std=c99" --enable-silent-rules --enable-shared --enable-dddmp --enable-obj --prefix=/home/Anton/cudd.no_target/cudd/build
make -j4
make check
make install
```

I am following CUDD [tutorial](https://davidkebo.com/cudd) with Visual Studio 2022 as per this [guide](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/setting-up-the-cu-decision-diagram-cudd-package-for-windows/). Cudd is linked as DLL because static linking gives errors.

This code fails with assertion at `fclose`:

```
/**
* Writes a dot file representing the argument DDs
* @param the node object
*/
void write_dd (DdNode *dd, char* filename)
{
FILE *outfile; // output file pointer for .dot file
outfile = fopen(filename,"w");
DdNode **ddnodearray = (DdNode**)malloc(sizeof(DdNode*)); // initialize the function array
ddnodearray[0] = dd;
Cudd_DumpDot(gbm, 1, ddnodearray, NULL, NULL, outfile); // dump the function to .dot file
free(ddnodearray);
fclose (outfile); // close the file */}
}
```

Assertion:

[image: close.cpp line 56]

Same code compiles and runs without any problem when using gcc.

I have tried to compile and run CUDD tests. MSVC rains with I/O assertions. GCC works fine.

What am I missing?

My goal is to write a .NET wrapper for CUDD as existing one ([PATBDD](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/%7Epat/bddlib/)) is missing both ADD and DDDMP functions.

There are no .NET-native binary decision tree/diagram libraries with basic functions like BDT->ROBDD, manual/dynamic variable reordering etc :(

Comment: Are you building the MSVC project in Debug mode or in Release mode? Whichever one, then maybe try the other? (Looks like you're in debug mode, from the shown error; the CUDD dll may demand only release-mode clients.)

Comment: Further, I think that, even if both DLL and EXE are built in "debug" mode, you won't necessarily have ABI compatibility between them, in terms of the debugger-mode additions. (Not sure, though.) In "release" mode, you should have ABI compatibility, if both are correctly targeted for the same Windows platform.

Comment: @AdrianMole indeed, it does not assert when running release config with MSVC; still output file is empty. Using stdout instead of file produces no output as well.

Comment: What's the return value of the call to `Cudd_DumpDot()`? Should be `1` (success) or `0` (failure); if the latter, there's likely a `Cudd_xxx` call to get info on the error.

Comment: @AdrianMole it returns 1 when configuration is Debug; Release build fails at this call: `(process 16864) exited with code -1073740791`. It is C0000409. It is security exception. It have had said me that fopen is unsecure. So std lib calls are not working at MSVC?

Comment: @AdrianMole print_dd function from same tutorial does work at both Release and Debug config

Comment: I very much doubt you can pass a `FILE *` from MSVC code to MinGW code.  They use different runtime libraries.

Comment: Just for info: Biddy (https://biddy.meolic.com/) is compiled with Visual Studio. Could it help you (it is not a CUDD clone).

Comment: @meolic thank you, I have tried biddy already. So far I have managed just to run Scout sample app. How to properly setup VS include dirs and lib paths for biddy? I have MSYS2 include dirs and VS include dirs. TCL/TK are installed. I have both Windows and MSYS2 versions.

Comment: @PaulSanders Indeed there are problems with std libraries. Can you advise on proper setup? From one end I have CUDD libary that can be compiled with gcc to static or dynamic library. On the other end there should be some managed C++ layer compiled with MSVC.

Comment: @meolic does Biddy have any ITE(condition, true_expr, false_expr) support? It is very handy to save/load BDD in that format. DD CUDD wrapper (Python) have that.

Comment: @AntonKrouglov Sorry, I can't.  You can pass `HANDLE`s around (because they're native to the OS), but not `FILE *`s (or any other runtime library construct).  Why don't you build it all with MinGW?

Comment: @PaulSanders I am building it all with MinGW right now. But I would eventually need to call it from C# or managed C++.

Comment: OK, why not build this `CUDD` thing (whatever it is) with MSVC then?

Comment: (I often find, btw, that I have to hack around with source code I bring into my projects from outside.  They don't build 'em like they used to.)

Comment: @PaulSanders I doubt that this will be an easy ride. It is mainly C originated from 1996 or so. So some code adaptation would be necessary. And I do not know yet how to convert autoconf-based build to MSVC solution.

Comment: I agree, it won't be.  But you'll wind up in a better place.

Comment: For Biddy support, please send email to the contact address down on the web page.

Comment: @PaulSanders thank you for a good idea. CUDD CMake config allowing MSVC/GCC  shell/VS/VSCode builds on either Windows or MinGW is available at https://github.com/antonKrouglov/cudd.CMake.